# JQuery Ajax request, Status 0, ResponseText is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have the following ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://forlineplus.forsa.com.co/projects/validar-redireccion-sio?fup=" + idFup,
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(param),
        //headers: {"Api-Key": authorizationToken},
        success: function (msg) {
            //var urlInJson = JSON.parse(msg);
            //ocultarLoad();
            urlResponseFromForline = "";
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //ocultarLoad();
            toastr.error(xhr.status + " / " + xhr.responseText + " \ " + thrownError, "FUP", {
                "timeOut": "0",
                "extendedTImeout": "0"
            });
        }
    });
```

I don't have idea with the response is always 0 in statusCode and the responseText is undefined, as you can see i have some lines commented, that's due to tests adding and removing headers, i have no idea what's happening, i just want to do that request and i have confirmed the api endpoint in postman, it works well
I have search some solutions on internet but no ones can solve my problem
Param object:

```
param = {
                "username": data.username,
                "id_user": data.id_user,
                "id_representative": data.id_representative,
                "id_role": data.id_role
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it's because you're not posting your data appropriately. From the [jQuery page on ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), the post parameters sent can be one of two formats:

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
> key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1',
> key2: 'value2'}.

Assuming that `param` is a regular object, you could send it unaltered...

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://forlineplus.forsa.com.co/projects/validar-redireccion-sio?fup=" + idFup,
        data: param,
        .....
```

Comment: I just made an update with the param object that i'm creating to send

Comment: Right, don't `JSON.stringify` it - just send the object per my answer and see if it helps. It might be erroring out due to a faulty request object

Comment: Same result :( i have removed the ```JSON.stringify``` and again status 0 and ResponseText is undefined

Comment: And, just to make sure, you're supposed to POST to a url that also has GET parameters? `https://forlineplus.forsa.com.co/projects/validar-redireccion-sio?fup=" + idFup`

Comment: Yeah, i have tested it in postman with this url for example: ```https://forlineplus.forsa.com.co/projects/validar-redireccion-sio?fup=56751``` and there works well, um, it have an Authorization Api-Key inside, in my Ajax code i have tried to put the headers {"Authorization":"xxx"} and {Api-Key:"xxx"} but same result, i mean if the key isn't present the endpoint return an error but with status and text